# On switching activity I am lossing activity bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

When I am switching from one activity to another I am losing my activity bar in which it should show title of activity.

[image]

On clicking on a particular list view I get following screen.

[image]

Code for DetailAcivity[ Second screenshot ] :

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        if(savedInstanceState == null ){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.detail_container, new DetailFragment())
                    .commit();

        }
    }

    public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment{
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            String forcastString = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text)).setText(forcastString);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Layouts of detail activities are as follow :

activity_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.DetailActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_detail.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

So can anyone help why my title bar is missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using different themes for activities in manifest.

Comment: No I am not using different theme in manifest

Comment: I have seen this behavior on One of the app also `Zomato` the restaurant app. What you can do is use `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Can you add code for first activity as well?

Comment: place the code for the first screenshot

Comment: @Maverik : Thanks Its problem with theme.

Comment: i dont think it has to do anything with the theme could you please post the code for the first screenshot?

Comment: try adding toolbar in your second screen

Comment: I have added activity using Andorid studio UI option. It by default added "appTheme.NoAppBar" in theme. When I removed NoAppBar part from theme it starts showing title bar.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include `toolbar` in your `DetailAcivity`. Include toolbar in your DetailAcivity just like you included it in your first activity